"javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message" when trying to read from a SSLSocket
I am writing a simple java proxy that prints the request of a client and then forwards it to the destination server. It must support SSL connections since most of the web pages are using HTTPS not plain HTTP. So I'm using SSLSockets instead of common Sockets.
But when I configure my browser to connect through the proxy and make a request, the connection is rejected and I got a SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
I suppose I am forgetting something regarding to the SSL configuration. Also, I am using renatoathaydes / rawhttp library for easy management of requests.
Here is the main method, that loops indefinitely to listen to new connections:
public static void main(String... args) {
        RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler();
        try {
            SSLServerSocketFactory factory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(8080);
            while (true) {
                SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
                Runnable action = () -> handler.handleRequest(sslSocket);
                Thread thread = new Thread(action);
                thread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

And the RequestHandler class is the responsable of read the client request, print to the logger and forward it to the server:
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestHandler {

    public void handleRequest(SSLSocket clientSocket) {
        try {
            RawHttpRequest request = readClientRequest(clientSocket);
            SSLSocket serverSocket = writeRequestToServer(request);

            log.info(request.toString().replace("\\n", ""));

            RawHttpRequest serverResponse = readResponseFromServer(serverSocket);
            writeResponseToClient(clientSocket, serverResponse);

            serverSocket.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    private RawHttpRequest readClientRequest(SSLSocket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        RawHttp http = new RawHttp();
        return http.parseRequest(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    }

    private void writeResponseToClient(SSLSocket clientSocket, RawHttpRequest response) throws IOException {
        response.writeTo(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    }

    private RawHttpRequest readResponseFromServer(SSLSocket serverSocket) throws IOException {
        RawHttp http = new RawHttp();
        return http.parseRequest(serverSocket.getInputStream());
    }

    private SSLSocket writeRequestToServer(RawHttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
        String host = httpRequest.getUri().getHost();
        int port = httpRequest.getUri().getPort();

        SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);

        httpRequest.writeTo(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
        return (sslSocket);
    }

}

I tried both SSL and plain HTTP connections, configuring the browser to connect through localhost and the specified port (8080). I changed the port to 443 which is a SSL port for what I red, but no effect.
Also tried without RawHttp library but it has the same issue.

Which exact version of the JDK? [edit] the question to add the complete error and exception stack trace

"But when I configure my browser to connect through the proxy" - your (undocumented) code fragments are confusing to me. And it is unclear how exactly you configure your browser to connect through the proxy. But I cannot see any attempts to either implement a HTTP proxy (which expects CONNECT requests for HTTPS) or a SOCKS proxy here. So there might be a fundamental misunderstanding on your part how a browser and a proxy communicate with each other. Note that this is not the same as how a browser and a HTTPS server do.
